# ¿Como puedo hacer que esto trabaje con String en lugar de con Integers?

Tags: java, string, integer

Necesito hacer que este codigo funcione con String, soy principiante y llevo bastante tiempo tratando de solucionarlo y nomas no puedo

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Numbers
{
public static void main (String[] args){
    Integer[] intList; 
    int size;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print ("\n¿Cúantos números enteros quieres ordenar? ");
    size = scan.nextInt();
    intList = new Integer[size];

    System.out.println ("\nDame los números...");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        intList[i] = scan.nextInt();
    Sorting.selectionSort(intList);
    System.out.println ("\nLos números ordenados son:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        System.out.print(intList[i] + " ");
    System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: tu programa es un metodo de ordenamiento,si les pasaras los datos como string,necesitaria pasarlos a int para poder ordenarlos,exactamente usando string que buscas que haga tu codigo?

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Antonio, si en lugar de usar scan.nextInt() para leer lo que escribes por la consola usas scan.nextLine() estarás trabajando con un String.

Además es más recomendable usar scan.nextLine(), y no hacer directamente el nextInt y luego si quieres siempre puedes convertir ese String al tipo que quieras haciendo un casteo de la siguiente forma:

```
String texto = scan.nextLine(); 
int numero = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

Comment: vale, ya quedo solucionando lo del nextLine() y cambiando los Integer por String

Comment: Me alegro Miguel!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando `scan.nextLine()` , así `size` pasará a ser de tipo `String` en lugar de `int`.